# unable to validate multiple inputs using angular

Tags: angular

here what i am trying i am trying to do is  validating multiple inputs(which are mentioned in array only those have to b validated) and the input are validated whether they are having a value or not input if the input is empty then the input border should be red the issue i am facing is i am able to apply to one input and but the same logic when it is applied to another inputs it is not applying in angular application but in stackblitz it is working

below is my code

```
data = [{ id: 1, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 6, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Tornado' }
  ]

  dataa = [
    {id:'test',name:'test'},
    {id:'address',name:'address'}
  ]

  @ViewChildren('ds') inps: QueryList<ElementRef>;
   @ViewChildren('dp') inp: QueryList<ElementRef>;


  check() {
    for (var x in this.inps) {
      let checkids: Array<number> = [2, 3, 6];
      if (x == "_results") {
        let id;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.inps[x].length; i++) {
          id = this.inps[x][i].nativeElement.getAttribute('id');
          if ((checkids.indexOf(+id) != -1) && !this.inps[x][i].nativeElement.value) {
            this.inps[x][i].nativeElement.style.borderColor = "red";
          }

        }
      }
    }
    for (var y in this.inp) {
      let checkid = ['address'];
      if (y == "_results") {
        let ids;
        for (var j = 0; j < this.inp[y].length; j++) {
          ids = this.inp[y][j].nativeElement.getAttribute('id');
          if ((checkid.indexOf(ids) != -1) && !this.inp[y][j].nativeElement.value) {
            this.inp[y][j].nativeElement.style.borderColor = "red";
          }

        }
      }
    }

  }
```

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let x of data">
    <input type="text" id={{x.id}} name={{x.name}} [ngModel]="sample" #ds>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div *ngFor="let y of dataa">
<input type="text" id={{y.id}} name={{y.name}} [ngModel]="sample" #dp>
</div>
<button type="button" (click)="check()">Check</button>
```

stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pw7bnb

Comment: Its not working because of checkids.indexOf(+id) != -1) condition. If you remove it will work. I am not sure what is the purpose of it . Why you need that condition that condition allows you to validate only 2,3,6 only

Comment: What is not working in your angular application. Can you debug your code at runtime that will help you where you went wrong, isn't it??

Comment: Is there a reason why you are accessing the DOM like this? This is not really the "Angularish" way :)

Comment: the input are not in reactive/template way and ng model already declared and using some other data so this is alternative approach

Answer (score 1):

You should be using attribute binding

```
<input type="text" [id]="x.id" [name]="x.name" [ngModel]="sample" #ds>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because of checkids.indexOf(+id) != -1) condition. If you remove it will work. I am not sure what is the purpose of it . Why you need that condition that condition allows you to validate only 2,3,6 only

Comment: the purpose is suppose if i have 5 fields like a,b,c,d in that i want to check only a,c,d are empty or not for that purpose i am using and if i dont use it will show to all fields

Comment: What is the exact issue . bec for me its working for second loop also

Comment: in Stackblitz the loop working but in the angular application it is not and i removed the checkids not the 2nd loop also working